# GridBagLayout, how can I stop my screen from stretching when I'm placing my components?

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

I'm using GridBagLayout and I like it quite a bit, but I'm having a problem with my screen stretching as I am placing and moving around my components. I think it has to do with my insets. I'm using insets to move and resize my components which I'm gonna guess is a big no-no in the coding world, but I don't really know how to do it another way. I am trying to make a form that someone can fill out and I want it to look neat and tidy.

Here is a picture of my program:
[image]

As you can see the name text field extends a lot farther than everything else, and this stretching got progressively worse as I used insets to modify my JComboBoxes.

Here is my code:

```
 vframe = new JFrame("MES Banking App");
 vpanel = new JPanel();
 titlelabel = new JLabel("Verification Page");
 namelabel = new JLabel("Name: ");
 namefield = new JTextField(20);
 birthdaylabel = new JLabel("Birth date: ");
 dayDD = new JLabel("Day:");
 daysArray = new String[] {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14","15","16","17","18"};//31
 BDday = new JComboBox(daysArray);
 monthDD = new JLabel("Month:");
 monthsArray = new String[] {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12"}; //12 months
 BDmonth = new JComboBox(monthsArray);



//title section
 vpanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
 grid = new GridBagConstraints();
 grid.fill = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START;
 grid.weightx = 0;
 grid.gridx = 0;
 grid.gridy = 0;
 vpanel.add(titlelabel,grid);

//name section
grid.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
grid.gridx = 0;
grid.gridy = 1;
grid.insets = new Insets(10,0,0,0);
vpanel.add(namelabel,grid);//adds name label
grid.gridx = 1;
grid.gridy = 1;
grid.insets = new Insets(0,0,0,0);
vpanel.add(namefield,grid); //adds name text field

//birthday section
grid.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
grid.gridx = 0;
grid.gridy = 2;
grid.insets = new Insets(0,0,0,0);
vpanel.add(birthdaylabel,grid); //adds bday label
grid.gridx = 1;
grid.gridy = 2;
vpanel.add(dayDD,grid); //add day label

grid.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
grid.gridx = 1;
grid.gridy = 2;
grid.insets = new Insets(0,30,0,350);//sets day drop down
vpanel.add(BDday,grid);

grid.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
grid.gridx = 1;
grid.gridy = 2;
grid.insets = new Insets(0,100,0,250);//month label
vpanel.add(monthDD,grid);

grid.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
grid.gridx = 1;
grid.gridy = 2;
grid.insets = new Insets(0,150,0,250);
vpanel.add(BDmonth,grid);



 vframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

 vframe.getContentPane().add(vpanel);  

 vframe.pack();
 vframe.setVisible(true);
```

Could someone demonstrate how to maneuver components in a way that doesn't stretch the screen? Editing my code works as well as explaining it in words, but I'm very visual and code snippets work best with me.

Thanks

Comment: try `vframe.setResizable(false);`

Comment: Look at using the MigLayout as a much better layout for creating forms.

Comment: Don't use insets to "move and resize". If you need an empty component placeholder, insert an empty JLabel into that grid spot.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels does that really work? is there anything build in that I can use?

Comment: @SoloSpirit: yes it really works, and yes you can use GridBagLayout, but use it correctly. Read the tutorials on it before using it. Please check out edits to answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using GridBagLayout and especially GridBagConstraints wrong as you're putting components right on top of each other. You need to make sure that you don't give the same component the same gridx and gridy position. Use GridWidth to stretch components out, but re-set it back again for the next component.  Don't use insets for this purpose. Note that it's often better to use new GridBagConstraints for each component. I often create a GridBagConstraints creating method just for this purpose.

e.g.,

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.*;

public class LayoutFoo2 {

   private static JFrame vframe;
   private static JPanel vpanel;
   private static JLabel titlelabel;
   private static JLabel namelabel;
   private static JTextField namefield;
   private static JLabel birthdaylabel;
   private static JLabel dayDD;
   private static String[] daysArray;
   private static JComboBox BDday;
   private static JLabel monthDD;
   private static String[] monthsArray;
   private static JComboBox BDmonth;
   private static GridBagConstraints grid;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      vframe = new JFrame("MES Banking App");
      vpanel = new JPanel();
      titlelabel = new JLabel("Verification Page");
      namelabel = new JLabel("Name: ");
      namefield = new JTextField(20);
      birthdaylabel = new JLabel("Birth date: ");
      dayDD = new JLabel("Day:");
      daysArray = new String[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9",
            "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18" };// 31
      BDday = new JComboBox(daysArray);
      monthDD = new JLabel("Month:");
      monthsArray = new String[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9",
            "10", "11", "12" }; // 12 months
      BDmonth = new JComboBox(monthsArray);

      // title section
      vpanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
      grid = new GridBagConstraints();
      grid.fill = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
      grid.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
      grid.weightx = 1.0;
      grid.weighty = 1.0;
      grid.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
      grid.gridx = 0;
      grid.gridy = 0;
      grid.gridwidth = 5;
      grid.gridheight = 1;
      vpanel.add(titlelabel, grid);

      // name section
      grid.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
      grid.gridwidth = 1;
      grid.gridx = 0;
      grid.gridy = 1;
      vpanel.add(namelabel, grid);// adds name label
      grid.gridx = 1;
      grid.gridy = 1;
      grid.gridwidth = 4;
      vpanel.add(namefield, grid); // adds name text field

      // birthday section
      grid.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
      grid.gridx = 0;
      grid.gridy = 2;
      grid.gridwidth = 1;
      vpanel.add(birthdaylabel, grid); // adds bday label
      grid.gridx = 1;
      grid.gridy = 2;
      vpanel.add(dayDD, grid); // add day label

      grid.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
      grid.gridx = 2;
      grid.gridy = 2;
      //!! grid.insets = new Insets(0, 30, 0, 350);// sets day drop down
      vpanel.add(BDday, grid);

      grid.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
      grid.gridx = 3;
      grid.gridy = 2;
      //!! grid.insets = new Insets(0, 100, 0, 250);// month label
      vpanel.add(monthDD, grid);

      grid.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
      grid.gridx = 4;
      grid.gridy = 2;
      //!! grid.insets = new Insets(0, 150, 0, 250);
      vpanel.add(BDmonth, grid);

      vframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

      vframe.getContentPane().add(vpanel);

      vframe.pack();
      vframe.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

---

So using two methods to simplify things:

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class LayoutFoo2 extends JPanel {

   private static final Insets DEFAULT_INSETS = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
   private static final double DEFAULT_WEIGHTX = 1.0;
   private static final double DEFAULT_WEIGHTY = 1.0;
   private static JFrame vframe;
   private static JPanel vpanel;
   private static JLabel titlelabel;
   private static JLabel namelabel;
   private static JTextField namefield;
   private static JLabel birthdaylabel;
   private static JLabel dayDD;
   private static String[] daysArray;
   private static JComboBox BDday;
   private static JLabel monthDD;
   private static String[] monthsArray;
   private static JComboBox BDmonth;
   private static GridBagConstraints grid;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      vframe = new JFrame("MES Banking App");
      vpanel = new JPanel();
      titlelabel = new JLabel("Verification Page");
      namelabel = new JLabel("Name: ");
      namefield = new JTextField(20);
      birthdaylabel = new JLabel("Birth date: ");
      dayDD = new JLabel("Day:");
      daysArray = new String[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9",
            "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18" };// 31
      BDday = new JComboBox(daysArray);
      monthDD = new JLabel("Month:");
      monthsArray = new String[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9",
            "10", "11", "12" }; // 12 months
      BDmonth = new JComboBox(monthsArray);

      // title section
      vpanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
      grid = createGbc(0, 0, 5, 1);
      grid.fill = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
      titlelabel.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
      vpanel.add(titlelabel, grid);

      // name section
      grid = createGbc(0, 1);
      vpanel.add(namelabel, grid);// adds name label

      grid = createGbc(1, 1, 4, 1);
      vpanel.add(namefield, grid); // adds name text field

      // birthday section
      grid = createGbc(0, 2);
      vpanel.add(birthdaylabel, grid); // adds bday label
      grid = createGbc(1, 2);
      vpanel.add(dayDD, grid); // add day label


      grid = createGbc(2, 2);
      vpanel.add(BDday, grid);

      grid = createGbc(3, 2);
      vpanel.add(monthDD, grid);
      grid = createGbc(4, 2);
      vpanel.add(BDmonth, grid);

      vframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

      vframe.getContentPane().add(vpanel);

      vframe.pack();
      vframe.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static GridBagConstraints createGbc(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
      GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
      gbc.gridx = x;
      gbc.gridy = y;
      gbc.gridwidth = width;
      gbc.gridheight = height;

      // default set ups
      gbc.insets = DEFAULT_INSETS;
      gbc.weightx = DEFAULT_WEIGHTX;
      gbc.weighty = DEFAULT_WEIGHTY;
      gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

      return gbc;
   }

   public static GridBagConstraints createGbc(int x, int y) {
      return createGbc(x, y, 1, 1);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hovercraft was faster, my `GridBagLayout` solution only cleans the example from multiple
duplicities:

```
package com.zetcode;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class GridBagBankingApp extends JFrame {

    public GridBagBankingApp() {

        initUI();

        setTitle("MES Banking App");
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private void initUI() {

        JLabel titlelabel = new JLabel("Verification Page");
        JLabel namelabel = new JLabel("Name: ");
        JTextField namefield = new JTextField(10);
        JLabel birthdaylabel = new JLabel("Birth date: ");
        JLabel dayDD = new JLabel("Day:");
        String[] daysArray = new String[]{"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
            "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", 
            "16", "17", "18"};// 31
        JComboBox BDday = new JComboBox(daysArray);
        JLabel monthDD = new JLabel("Month:");
        String[] monthsArray = new String[]{"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
            "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"}; // 12 months
        JComboBox BDmonth = new JComboBox(monthsArray);

        //title section
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints grid = new GridBagConstraints();
        grid.fill = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        grid.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);   
        grid.gridwidth = 5;
        add(titlelabel, grid);

        //name section
        grid.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        grid.gridwidth = 1;
        grid.gridy = 1;
        add(namelabel, grid);

        grid.gridx = 1;
        grid.gridwidth = 4;
        add(namefield, grid); 

        //birthday section
        grid.gridx = 0;
        grid.gridy = 2;
        grid.gridwidth = 1;
        add(birthdaylabel, grid); 

        grid.gridx = 1;
        add(dayDD, grid); 

        grid.gridx = 2;
        add(BDday, grid);

        grid.gridx = 3;
        add(monthDD, grid);

        grid.gridx = 4;
        add(BDmonth, grid);

        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                GridBagBankingApp ex = new GridBagBankingApp();
                ex.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Instead of `GridBagLayout`, use `MigLayout` manager. Unlike `MigLayout`, which creates
a whole grid in one shot, in `GridBagLayout` we have to define each cell
individually. This is tiresome and error-prone.

`MigLayout` is much more portable. In `GridBagLayout's` solution, we have
defined insets the following way:

```
grid.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
```

This may be OK on a certain resolution. On others, it is not correct. (It could
be too small and ruining our entire layout.) `MigLayout` creates gaps between
components that are screen resolution and DPI independent. For this reasons,
we should avoid using `GridBagLayout` and use either `MigLayout` or `GroupLayout` 
managers.

```
package com.zetcode;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;


public class MigLayoutBankingApp extends JFrame {

    public MigLayoutBankingApp() {

        initUI();
        setTitle("MES Banking App");
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);        
    }

    private void initUI() {

        JPanel pnl = new JPanel(new MigLayout());

        JLabel titleLbl = new JLabel("Verification Page");
        JLabel nameLbl = new JLabel("Name: ");
        JTextField nameField = new JTextField(10);
        JLabel bdLbl = new JLabel("Birth date: ");
        JLabel dayDD = new JLabel("Day:");
        String[] daysArray = new String[]{"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
            "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", 
            "16", "17", "18" };
        JComboBox BDday = new JComboBox(daysArray);
        JLabel monthDD = new JLabel("Month:");
        String[] monthsArray = new String[]{"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
            "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"}; // 12 months
        JComboBox BDmonth = new JComboBox(monthsArray);        

        pnl.add(titleLbl, "spanx, center, wrap");
        pnl.add(nameLbl);
        pnl.add(nameField, "spanx, growx, wrap");
        pnl.add(bdLbl);
        pnl.add(dayDD);
        pnl.add(BDday);
        pnl.add(monthDD);
        pnl.add(BDmonth);

        add(pnl);

        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MigLayoutBankingApp ex = new MigLayoutBankingApp();
                ex.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

As we can clearly see, the code is much shorter.

[image]

Comment: First, the question is about using GridBagLayout and does not ask for replacements.  Second, you did not address the cost of dependency on a third-party library.  Finally, it was debatable whether a string is less error-prone than explicit GridBagConstraints.

Comment: 1+ up-vote to counter-act the down-vote. Yours is a decent solution that uses what I feel is a more robust, easier to use, easier to enhance layout manager.

Comment: I honestly like both of your answers a lot, thanks guys.